# Creating a Word Dcoument in code behind c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

I have used an example from microsoft on how to created a word document from code behind. I have implemented this code in a simple web part in order to test it first. I have a button that when pressed whould created the Word Document, but currently nothing happens when the button is clicked. I am not sure what I am missing here so I hope somebody could provide an insight, below is the code I currently have: (I will just list the importat parts

---

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Server; //for use when creatigna   writing data to a MS  
                               //Word  Document
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; //for use when creatigna   writing data to a MS 
                                     //Word Documenr
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; //for use when creatign and  writing data 
                                            //to a MS Word Document
using System.Reflection;

namespace Kemp.SP2010.Badges.Badges
{
public partial class BadgesUserControl : UserControl
{




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

GenerateBadges.Click += new EventHandler(GenerateBadges_Click);

}



//button to create the badges
void GenerateBadges_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{


#region Create Table in MS Word Document


object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; 

//Start word and create a new document
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


//Creating  a paragraph at the beginning of the document
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oPara1.Range.Text = "Heading 1";
oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24; //24 pt spacing after paragraph
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

//Creating an 2x8 table
Word.Table oTable;
Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, 2, 8, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;

//for loop
int r,c;
string strText;
for (r = 1; r <= 2; r++)
for (c = 1; c <= 8; c++)
{

strText = "r" + r +"c" + c;
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = strText;

}

oTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
oTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Italic = 1;

#endregion
}
}
}
```

---

And here is the web part with the button

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" 
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" 
Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" 
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="BadgesUserControl.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="Kemp.SP2010.Badges.Badges.BadgesUserControl" %>

<!--Button to generate the Badges in a MS Word Document-->

<tr>
<td valign="top" width="100%">

<asp:Button ID="GenerateBadges" runat="server" Text="Generate Badges" />

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

This shoould in theory create a Word Document with a paragraph and a table when the Button is selected. But as mentioned earlier nothing happens.

Any sugestions will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: You need a full installation of MS Word on the server for this to work.

Comment: BTW: The namespace `Microsoft.Office.Server` is deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrestling with the [Open Document libraries from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx). They have a horrible API but:

- Can produce docx files which are the native format supported by MS Word 2007+
- Do not require an installation of MS Word (in fact are 100% .NET code).
- Actually support most versions of word [via the compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=941B3470-3AE9-4AEE-8F43-C6BB74CD1466&displaylang=en) (you can get them to open in Word 2000 or later).
- Are also supported by recent versions of Open Office

Comment: This sounds tempting, but then that means having to istall it and configure it on our dev environment. There must be a simpler way to create or open word document at the click of a webaprt button

Comment: All you need is to add a reference to the .NET assembly. You're not going to get any simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Open XML Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465%28v=office.12%29.aspx) instead. It only works with docx documents though, but is very simple when it comes to making Office Word documents or manipulating word documents